# (WebSphere 7.0) Error Parsing a CoreGroup document

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-rad, ibm-was

I'm currently trying to run a **websphere 7.0 server** ***localy*** in Rational Application Developer (**RAD**). Whenever I start the server I get "**Error parsing a coregroup document**". Has anyone faced this kind of problem? If so, what is a **coregroup** document and of course what is the solution?

**Stacktrace :**

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationError: com.ibm.wsspi.hamanager.HAException: Error parsing a CoreGroup document
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.Config.initialize(Config.java:184)
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.CoordinatorComponentImpl.initialize(CoordinatorComponentImpl.java:204)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1073)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:874)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:780)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:754)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:666)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:330)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:108)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.hamanager.HAException: Error parsing a CoreGroup document
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.CoreGroupConfig.<init>(CoreGroupConfig.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.StateBlobBuilder.buildBlob(StateBlobBuilder.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.Config.initialize(Config.java:180)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.CoreGroupLiveness.<init>(CoreGroupLiveness.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.CoreGroupConfig.<init>(CoreGroupConfig.java:110)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Did you try to create fresh AppServer profile, as maybe the profile is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate from WAS V6.1? If you did then you are seeing the problem described in APAR PK82319,
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PK82319
Upgrade WAS V7 to 7.0.0.3 or higher and do the migrate again.

If not a migration, then look at the coregroup documents here:
/config/cells//coregroups